# How can I delay rendering until then() of promise completes?

Tags: reactjs, redux, es6-promise

I'm using reactjs with redux and this is a part of one of my components.

I want to render `postList` of the promise which is returned by `handleFetchPosts`, but the `render()` function starts rendering before the `then()` of `shouldComponentUpdate` is completed.

How can I postpone rendering or rerender after the `then` is completed?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.postList = props.postList;
    this.props.handleFetchPosts('/main', 'about', '');
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (this.postList !== nextProps.postList) {
        nextProps.postList.then(data => {
            this.postList = data;
        });
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="content">
            <p>
                {this.postList + ""}
                {/*content*/}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You have to add a test on your render to check if your `state.poplist` is filled before rendering the poplist. Yuo can render a 'loading' when it's not filled.

Comment: Umm... can you show me an example with codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, I've totally changed my answer, I bypassed the fact you are using Redux.

The fact that you're using Redux, I'd set up an async action that shouldComponentUpdate calls, which kick-starts the Promise call.
This way you can update a flag in your state after starting the Promise to use in the render method to prevent rendering. 
Once the call has finished send the final ACTION with the results and change the flag back.

Comment: I think it can prevent rendering but this code cannot notify whether the `shouldRender` is changed or not because `render()` function is executed asynchronously while `this.shouldRender = true;` statement of the `then()` is running.

Comment: I apologize for my late feedback. Your guide was greatly helpful to me and I solved my problem. Thanks a lot! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For manage your component rendering use the `state` of your component. and update it when you receive your data.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      postList:this.props.postList;
    }
    this.props.handleFetchPosts('/main', 'about', '');
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (this.postList !== nextProps.postList) {
        nextProps.postList.then(data => {
            this.setState({
              postList:data
            });
        });
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

render() {
    if(!this.state.postList){
      return <div>Loading</div>
    }
    return (
        <div className="content">
            <p>
                {this.state.postList + ""}
                {/*content*/}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm using Redux. Doesn't it violate the 'single source of truth' if I update a state variable out of the store?

Comment: Up to you, but using local component state is fine [redux FAQ](https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#do-i-have-to-put-all-my-state-into-redux-should-i-ever-use-reacts-setstate)

Comment: In this case use redux and not local variable `this.propList`. Use the state of your store ine the render and instanciation